# Converting an object in ASP.net MVC Razor to JSON, to add to form attribute encodes double quotes

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, razor

Using the MvcForm HtmlHelper, I have added 'id' and 'data-values' attributes to a form in an ASP.NET MVC Razor view.

I created a new object 'DataVars' to hold local and Model values. Then I converted 'DataVars' object into a JSON object and added it to the form tag  'data-values' attribute to be referenced later by JavaScript on the client-side.

```
@{
    var DataVars = new
    {
        var1= LocalVar,
        var2= Model.var1
    };

    var testing = Json.Encode(DataVars);
 }

@using (Html.BeginRouteForm("GetForm", FormMethod.Get, new
{
    id = "formId",
    data_values = @Html.Raw(testing)
})) {
    <div class="form-element-group">
        <label class="screen-reader-only" for="terms">@T("Tooltip")</label>
        <input type="text" class="text" id="terms" autocomplete="off" name="q" placeholder="@T("Tooltip")" />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <input type="submit" class="button" value="@T("Button")" />
        </span>
    </div>
}
```

This all works, but the problem is, in the resulting HTML output in the form 'data-values' attribute, double quotes are encoded within the JSON object;

```
data-values="{&quot;var1&quot;:&quot;text info&quot;,&quot;var2&quot;:0}"
```

When stepping through the code in debug the value for variable testing is set to:

```
{\"var1\":\"text info\",\"var2\":0}
```

Is there a way to force the JSON to be;

```
data-values="{"var1":"text info","var2":0}"
```

Comment: Basically JSON wants double-quotes, but you can use single quotes on HTML attributes (works on all browsers). Unfortunately you will need to override the default behaviour of the attribute writing to do this.

Comment: @GoneCoding Are you recommending overriding the MvcForm HtmlHelper?

Comment: I would normally add a custom Html *helper extension method* and take full control of the output.

Comment: Otehrwise drop it into a normal HTML element: `<div class="form-element-group" data-values='@Html.Raw(testing)'>`

Comment: Ok, cheers @GoneCoding, I will look into adding a custom Html helper extension method.